# I cannot remove mysql-server-5.7

Tags: apt, server, package-management, dpkg, mysql

I am trying to remove mysql with the following commands:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-*
sudo apt autoremove
```

and got these errors:

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--remove):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

what can I do to remove this mysql-server-5.7
. After `sudo apt-get install -f`
I got:

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
dpkg -s mysql-server-5.7
Package: mysql-server-5.7
Status: install ok half-configured
Priority: optional
Section: database
Installed-Size: 46369
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: mysql-5.7
Version: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
Replaces: mysql-client-5.5, mysql-server-5.5, mysql-server-5.6 (<< 5.7), virtual-mysql-server
Provides: virtual-mysql-server
Depends: bsdutils, lsb-base (>= 3.0-10), mysql-client-5.7 (>= 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4), mysql-common (>= 5.8+1.0.4~), mysql-server-core-5.7 (= 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4), passwd, perl (>= 5.6), psmisc, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, libc6 (>= 2.14), libevent-core-2.1-6 (>= 2.1.8-stable), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), liblz4-1 (>= 0.0~r127), libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Pre-Depends: adduser (>= 3.40), debconf, mysql-common (>= 5.5)
Recommends: libhtml-template-perl
Suggests: mailx, tinyca
Breaks: mysql-server-5.6 (<< 5.7)
Conflicts: mysql-client-5.5, mysql-server-5.5, virtual-mysql-server
Conffiles:
 /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld 7faefe6d3d191f1e9ec1094ac8e0b159
 /etc/init.d/mysql 89a1a5b6ad710389112802fc3fbb81e1
 /etc/init/mysql.conf 5b097f4a577d63c60a8f6ca01b12bc47
 /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.paranoid/mysql-server-5_7 6babe46e791059cdd5a26f4f7fec9eca
 /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/mysql-server-5_7 2d34a7ed83fefc165cd1dfea3a72ccc8
 /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.workstation/mysql-server-5_7 2d34a7ed83fefc165cd1dfea3a72ccc8
 /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server b3c32cbc55b042b1fe76698c8e928974
 /etc/mysql/debian-start 68f4d300f151fd3facec50d0bcf009ef
 /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf f5d3113b607567fd2ce955f4279fa9ce
 /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf cae4bc0923e3a19cdfe3c85c06fbbfb7
 /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf 347fa9f3d579ffc06c39bf7e69f4fc6e
Description: MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
 MySQL is a fast, stable and true multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database
 server. SQL (Structured Query Language) is the most popular database query
 language in the world. The main goals of MySQL are speed, robustness and
 ease of use.
 .
 This package contains all the infrastructure needed to setup system
 databases.
Homepage: http://dev.mysql.com/
```

Comment: So did you stop mysql before doing this? Or is it currently running?

Comment: yes, I stoped with this sudo systemctl stop mysql

Comment: did you try: `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*` ?

Comment: yes, same error